# How to show an image in imagebox and specify a value for combo when i select a row of dateagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml

I get some field of a table and show them in a datagrid with this code:

in XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgvAddPersonTab"  Height="158" Width="396" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectionChanged="dgvAddPersonTab_SelectionChanged" Canvas.Left="520" Canvas.Top="20">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="78" />
        <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Family}" Width="80" />
        <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding DepartmentName}" Width="78" />
        <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Occupation}" Width="80" />
        <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding PersonalCardNo}" Width="78" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and in code behind:

```
var queryOfDGVAddPerson = from j in FaceDB.tblknownPeoples
                                      join m in FaceDB.tblDepartments
                                      on j.IdDepartment equals m.IdDepartment
                                      select new { j.FirstName, j.Family, m.DepartmentName, j.Occupation, j.PersonalCardNo, j.BirthDate, j.FatherName, j.FifthPicAddress, j.FirstPicAddress, j.fourthPicAddress, j.IdDepartment, j.NationalIDCardNo, j.Phone, j.SecondPicAddress, j.ThirdPicAddress };

            dgvAddPersonTab.ItemsSource = queryOfDGVAddPerson.ToList();
```

Now, I want when i select a row in datagrid, all fields corresponding to the row in that table is shown in some textbox
and combo and imagebox. I can get all fields with follow code:

```
object ob = datagrid.SelectedItem;
```

but i can't show them, especially i have problem with combo 
and imagebox. I must say that in field corresponding with imagebox is saved address of an image.

UPDATED:
I found a way to show string that fetch from table in a textbox but i can't still have found a way to show image by its address and combovalue.

```
public IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(DataGrid grid)
    {
        var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
        if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
        foreach (var item in itemsSource)
        {
            var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
            if (null != row) yield return row;
        }
    }

    private void dgvAddPersonTab_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            var row_list = GetDataGridRows(dgvAddPersonTab);
            foreach (DataGridRow single_row in row_list)
            {
            if (single_row.IsSelected == true)
            {
                txtName.Text = Convert.ToString(TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(single_row.DataContext)["FirstName"].GetValue(single_row.DataContext));

            }
            }
    }
```

Second Update:

Suppose i have two table named `person` and  `OfficeAccess`. In `person` i'll save the staffs of office and in `OfficeAccess` i save access of this staffs to office's building. `person` has this field: `IdKnown`, `name`, `family`, `phone`, `IdAccess` and `OfficeAccess` has this field: `IdAccess`, `AccessDeccription`. `IdAccess` foreign key in person have a reference to `OfficeAccess` and `IdAccess` column. Now, after this long intro(!), The value of combo come from `OfficeAccess` and `AccessDeccription`.

I try with follow code but it was wrong:

```
cmbAccessOfOffice.DisplayMemberPath = dgvAddPersonAllFeilds.GetType().GetProperty("DepartmentName").GetValue(dgvAddPersonAllFeilds, null).ToString();
```

Comment: what r u trying to do ?

Comment: i try to show all field that saved to table to edit them.

Comment: where are your combobox and imagebox ?

Comment: ur question is still unclear, I cant see anything related to Image in your question.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan justin's answer would clear my purpose and his answer was right about image and string. but how about combo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
   var obj = dgvAddPersonTab.SelectedItem;
            var nameOfProperty = "DepartmentName";
            var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(nameOfProperty);
            var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);           
            img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ToString()));
```

Combobox:

When you are creating combobox you need to set the SelectedValuePath.And you can use the same method above to select the combobox value

```
 var obj = dgvAddPersonTab.SelectedItem;
                var nameOfProperty = "ComoBoxProperty";
                var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(nameOfProperty);
                var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);

cmbAccessOfOffice.SelectedValue=value ;
```

Comment: Excellent , It work. but how do i show a value in a combo with your way?
THX SO MUCH.

Comment: @Saeid  combobox is already filled and you want to select a item inside combox according to Datagrid selection. is that right?

Comment: @Saeid Updated the answer

Comment: hey guy thank you so much... now it work with your guidance.