# How to show a value in combobox when i select a row of datagrid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a daetagrid and a combobox and a textbox in a window in wpf.

in xmal:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtCameraName"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCameraType" SelectedValuePath="Camera_Type" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Text="Please select...">
    <ComboBoxItem>IP</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>webcam</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>analogue</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<DataGrid x:Name="mydgv" SelectionChanged="dgvAddPersonTab_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Camera_Name}" Width="80" />
        <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Camera_Type}" Width="80" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

I get all fields of a table named mytbl and show them in datagrid with this code:

```
    private void window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var q= from j in CamDB.mytbl select q;
        mydgv.ItemsSource = q.ToList();
    }
```

and `mytbl` is a table that it has two field : `Camera_Name`, `Camera_Type`. Now I want to show value of `Camera_Name` in textbox and value of `Camera_Type` in combo when I select a row of datagrid. I read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072853/how-to-show-an-image-in-imagebox-and-specify-a-value-for-combo-when-i-select-a-r) and I tried with following code but it worked about textbox while it didn't work about combo.

```
    private void mydgv_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var AllFields = mydgv.SelectedItem;
        txtCameraName.Text = AllFields.GetType().GetProperty("Camera_Name").GetValue(AllFields, null).ToString();
        cmbCameraType.SelectedValue = AllFields.GetType().GetProperty("Camera_Type").GetValue(AllFields, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following code and it works:

```
    cmbCameraType.Text = AllFields.GetType().GetProperty("Camera_Type").GetValue(AllFields, null).ToString();
```

Comment: All this can be done simpler in xaml with binding. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding?

Try adding these to the TextBox and ComboBox in xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=mydgv,Path=SelectedItem.Camera_Name" />
<ComboBox Text="{Binding ElementName=mydgv,Path=SelectedItem.Camera_Type" />
```

Other things were omitted.

Comment: Yes, because I see now that you are trying to edit the Text property of the ComboBox. ComboBoxes are usually not used that way. But if you really want, check my updated answer. It should work now. Let me know.

Comment: your update answer worked in textbox but still doesn't work on combo.

Comment: Ok, thank you for letting me know. But anyway, you're probably doing things wrong. You should be assigning value to the SelectedItem property of the ComboBox, not the Text ...